# Can I completely get rid of Windows on my computer and transfer its storage space to Ubuntu from Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, xubuntu, windows, storage

I have dual boot on my computer: Windows 8 and Xubuntu. I won't be using Windows anymore and would like, therefore, to get rid of Windows completely, transferring all of the storage space to Xubuntu. Is it simple to do that can be done from the terminal?

I did `sudo parted-l` and got

```
Model: ATA WDC WD5000LPVX-2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  368MB  367MB   primary   ntfs            boot
 2      368MB   257GB  257GB   primary   ntfs
 3      257GB   500GB  243GB   extended
 5      257GB   259GB  2047MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 6      259GB   500GB  241GB   logical   ext4
```

Comment: It can be done from terminal, but it is possibly easier to do whit an gui app like gparted. Please update your question with the output of `sudo parted -l` or a screen-dump of gparted  ... I prefere gparted.

Comment: @SorenA just did this

Comment: @kiabbo there are a few things you need to consider, right now it looks like you are using the windows partition to be your boot loader.  You will have to think about how you are going to make grub take control of that, an set up a boot partition, and then after that the rest you can use as another drive so you can mount that for your use, by adding it to your /etc/fstab.